# Prove that $||\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{x_n}||\le\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}||{x_n}||$ when series $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{x_n}$ are absolutely converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I think it should be proved that:

Since

$$||\sum_{n=0}^{N}{x_n}||\le\sum_{n=0}^{N}||{x_n}||$$

so

$$\lim_{N\to+\infty}||\sum_{n=0}^{N}{x_n}||\le\lim_{N\to+\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{N}||{x_n}||$$
so

$$||\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{x_n}||\le\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}||{x_n}||$$ 
is it right ??

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: For greater clarity, you can take the two limits in different steps, $$\| \sum_{n=0}^N x_n\| \le \sum_{n=0}^N\|x_n\| \le \sum_{n=0}^\infty \|x_n\|,$$ where the last inequality follows because the remainder of the series is always positive. After that you consider the limit of a bounded sequence, which is to be found within the same bounds.